# MongoDB problem on Upgrade from Spring Boot 2.2.x to 2.3x

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have a very confusing problem with upgrading my spring-boot/mongodb-driver. As database, we are running a mongodb:4.0 instance.

Before I had

```
Spring Boot 2.2.8
"mongo-java-driver|async|mongo-java-driver-reactivestreams", version: "3.11.2|1.12.0"
```

and switched now to

```
Spring Boot 2.3.4
"mongo-java-driver|reactive-streams", version: "4.0.5"
```

In our ci-test-pipeline, all is fine with that with a mongodb-testcontainer with the same image. Also connecting from my IDE with that running App to our Databases results in no problems.

But: On our Test-System, sometimes it starts-up as fast as usual, sometimes it takes 3-6x longer to startup, sometimes it event wont start after 10 minutes. On our "bigger test system", I never reached the phase of "after startup" after upgrading (which may give the hint it can be depending on size of data?).

When I look into the Mongo Logs, I cant see there any executed queries or requested index builds, which may enlarge startup time. I only realized some behaviours changed, e.g. count query shifted to be now an aggregation (but this query manually executed was also fast).

On my application, the only thing showing up are logs like this

```
org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command      : Sending command '{"ismaster": 1, "$db": "admin"}' with request id 203 to database admin on connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:107164}] to server XXX
org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command      : Execution of command with request id 203 completed successfully in 1.15 ms on connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:107164}] to server XXX
org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Updating cluster description to  {type=STANDALONE, servers=[{address=XXX, type=STANDALONE, roundTripTime=1.7 ms, state=CONNECTED}]
org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Checking status of XXX
```

I don't really know where to debug further, as all works fine from my local machine, and I can also see that data is while starting-up transferred from database, so there is no problem with finding the database it principle.

EDIT: After a fresh new checkout, I also face the same result from my local project, so it seems there have to be some cached stuff which has not been cleaned away which did help spring to skip that connection problem.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow after Upgrade, MongoCollectionImpl.doCount(..) wont deliver results before startup, and just idle the main-thread. I managed to skip my couting and do it somewhere later and now it works.